# ExtJS 6 how to capture the selection on a dynamic radiogroup or and a checkboxgroup

Tags: extjs

I am trying to capture the selected radio from a radiogroup or the selected checkboxes from a checkbox group that are being populated dymaically. I have a component which receives properties and the data and it constructs the radios or the checkboxes dynamically. It does that as expected, but, how to capture the selecion? Here is what I have so far:

```
    Ext.define('mycomp', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.WidgetProp',
    collapsible: false,

    initComponent: function () {
        const that = this;
        const id = this.id;

        const items = [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                defaultType: that.propType === 'radio' ? 'radiofield' : 'checkboxfield',
                defaults: {
                    flex: 1
                },
                layout: 'vbox',
                columns: 2,
                vertical: true,
                simpleValue: true,
                items: that.dataList.map(function (x) {
                    const item = {
                        boxLabel: x.boxLabel,
                        name: x.name,
                        inputValue: x.inputValue,
                        id: x.id
                    };
                    return item;
                }),
                listeners: {
                   change: function(item, newval, oldval, eopts) {
                       console.log('clicked', item, newcal, oldval, eopts);
                   }
                } 
            }
        ];
        this.items = items;
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

but it does not work at all, it does not print nothing on the console, I tried with `change`, `click`, `beforechange`, I tried with a `handler` but nothing seems to be working. Any hint on how to achieve this? Am I calling the event the right way? Why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FieldContainer does not have change event, it is just container. The listeners must be located in the radio or check -fields.

```
Ext.define('mycomp', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.WidgetProp',
    collapsible: false,
    dataList: [],

    initComponent: function () {
        const that = this;
        const id = this.id;

        const items = [{
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            defaultType: that.propType === 'radio' ? 'radiofield' : 'checkboxfield',
            defaults: {
                flex: 1
            },
            layout: 'vbox',
            columns: 2,
            vertical: true,
            simpleValue: true,
            items: that.dataList.map(function (x) {
                const item = {
                    boxLabel: x.boxLabel,
                    name: x.name,
                    inputValue: x.inputValue,
                    id: x.id,
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (item, newVal, oldVal, eopts) {
                            console.log('clicked', newVal, oldVal, eopts);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return item;
            })
        }];
        this.items = items;
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3728)